# How to set Playwright not automatically follow the redirect?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I want to open a website using Playwright,
but I don't want to be automatically redirected.

In some other web clients, they have parameter link `follow=False` to disable automatically following the redirection. But I can't find it on Playwright.

```py
async def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = await chromium.launch()
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = await context.new_page()

    def handle_response(response):
        print(f'status: {response.status} {response.url}')
    page.on('response', handle_response)

    await page.goto("https://google.com")
    await browser.close()
```

that's the sample code, as we know google.com would respond 301 and will be redirected to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
Is it possible to stop the process after I got the 301, so I don't need to continue processing [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and all the responses after that?

From the [Request documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-request), I got that `Page.on('response')` emitted when/if the response status and headers are received for the request.

But how to stop the Request after the Page got on('response') callback?
I saw some other questions similar, using Route.abort() or Route.fulfill(), but I still don't get the answer for my case.

thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm following this pull request to see if it solves this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/pull/17033

Answer (score 1):

As introduced in **v1.26**,may use [maxRedirects](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-get-option-max-redirects) optional argument in get requests.

This provides as maximum number of request redirects that will be followed automatically. An error will be thrown if the number is exceeded. Defaults to 20. Pass 0 to not follow redirects.

References:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-get-option-max-redirects

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-get-option-max-redirects

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/pull/17033

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/12911

Comment: How can it be applied to the `.goto` function in the example code?

Answer (score 1):

While you might use the solution outlined by Vishal for generic API requests, it's not that easy while working in the browser context and using `page.goto()`.
I found a hint in a [closed issue from 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20213) and put together a working solution:

```js
await page.route('**', async route => {
    const response = await route.fetch({maxRedirects: 0});
    let headers = response.headers();
    delete headers['location'];
    delete headers['Location'];
    return route.fulfill({
        response: response,
        headers: headers
    });
});
response = await page.goto(req.query.url, {
    timeout: timeout,
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
});
```

In this solution, [`page.route()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-route) is used to configure how requests made by `page.goto()` should be handled. First, we tell the browser to not follow initial redirects: `route.fetch({maxRedirects: 0})`. Additionally, as route.fulfill() seems to follow redirects instructed by location headers, we remove any location header from the response and then pass everything to the fulfill() function.

Caution: this may break rending of websites if the website references assets such as images or CSS files, which itself are redirected. You may tweak the `page.route()` part to your use case.